# How do I count the total number of rows returned from a WQL query?

Tags: powershell, wql

I am trying to find the total number of CPUs on a computer via `get-wmiobject`. The query: `select * from win32_processor` returns more than 1 row if there is more than 1 processor on the computer. WQL doesn't have the `count` keyword like in TSQL. So I am just wondering whether there is another way to find the total number of rows returned?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just force it into an array and use the `Count` property:

```
@(gwmi win32_processor).count
```

For the specific case, if you are just looking for number of processors, you can do:

```
$env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS
```

Comment: I do need the other bits of information from win32_processor as well, but thanks for the second suggestion!

Comment: `@(gwmi win32_processor).count`will return the number of physical processors. `$env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS` will return the number of logical processors.

Answer (score 4):

You can also try the `Win32_OperatingSystem` class:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName localhost | `
   Select-Object NumberOfProcessors,NumberOfLogicalProcessors
```